# The text delimited layer is not appearing

Tags: qgis, point, csv

I've been trying to add a certain CSV file as a points layer to QGIS for a while now, without much success.
When I add it as a delimited text file in QGIS with "," as the expression delimiter, the sample looks good. Still, the point coordinates are not shown on the map when I choose long and lat as the x and y coordinates, respectively.

I'm not sure what goes wrong, as I have earlier successfully added other point layers in QGIS.

Why can the linked CSV file above not be added properly as a points layer file in QGIS?

Note: here's an example of a coordinate tuple of the CSV file I'm trying to upload:

17.99662 ; 696585.0035
The CRS of my own project is EPSG: 32642 . I've tried adding the points layer in both this CRS and in EPSG: 4326.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the data. You don't have the correct CRS. 17.99662, 696585.0035 in EPSG: 32642 is [in the ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snewk.png). And it can't be a lon, lat in EPSG:4326 because 696585 is far too large a number.

Comment: user2856 this points are just an example. 696585.0035 yes this is incorrect but my excel is calculating the formula so cant solve this proble. I understood that the problem is with my decimal degrees that have an incorrect format, but i cant change the format of the points

Comment: As I commented,  you need to provide more information about the data.